# Проблема с таймерами

Tags: javascript, анимация, таймер

Суть всей задачи, которую я себе придумал - нужно сделать так, чтобы первый объект запускался функцией setInterval, причём не важно сколько раз, а затем легко останавливал ВСЕ циклы с помощью ПКМ.
Это я успешно сделал.

Второй объект должен запускаться на таких же условиях, но с дополнительной функцией setTimeout, которая, в данном случае окрашивает фон в синий цвет.

Проблемы:

1. У меня не останавливается функция setTimeout.
2. Я не знаю как ограничить запуск второй функции, чтобы её можно было запустить всего-лишь 1 раз и не более.
3. Я не знаю как сделать так, чтобы нажатие ПКМ по второму объекту, не останавливал первый.

Подскажите пожалуйста, в голове идея есть, а все справочники предоставляют решения через if'ы и всякие jquerry, с которым я еще не знаком, т.е. обойтись надо как-то без них.

https://repl.it/FgsA/29

```js
var $rot = 0;
var $rot2 = 0;
var $contextmenu = 0;
var $timerId = [];
var $timerId2 = 0;
var $timerId3 = [];

function rotinp($pl) {
  $rot = $rot + $pl;
  document.getElementById('im1').style.transform = "rotate(" + $rot + "deg)";
}

function rotinp2($pl) {
  $rot2 = $rot2 + $pl;
  document.getElementById('im2').style.transform = "rotate(" + $rot2 + "deg)";
}

function my_click($event) {
  $timerId.push(setInterval("rotinp(30);", 60));
  $click++
}

function my_click2($event) {
  $timerId3.push(setTimeout("colinp('blue');", 3000));
  $timerId2 = setInterval("rotinp2(-30);", 60);
  $click++;
}

function colinp($pl) {
  document.getElementById('im3').style.backgroundColor = $pl;
}

function my_contextmenu($event) {
  $event.preventDefault();
  $timerId.forEach(clearInterval).length = 0;
  $timerId3.forEach(clearTimeout).length = 0;
  $contextmenu++;
}
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: separate;
}
td {
  padding: 28px;
}
```

```html
<table border="1px">
  <tr>
    <td onClick="my_click(event);" onContextMenu="my_contextmenu(event);">
      <img id="im1" src="https://pp.vk.me/c637619/v637619597/38a2a/-FsXr_IGLuI.jpg" width="130">
    </td>
    <td id="im3" onClick="my_click2(event);" onContextMenu="my_contextmenu(event);">
      <img id="im2" src="https://pp.vk.me/c637619/v637619597/38a31/ik9uDnLPS4E.jpg" width="130">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

1) Организуйте свой код.

- Код написан в кодстайле неподходящем JS,
- Не надо именовать переменные с $ - это делается обычно для переменных обернутых jQuery,
- setInterval и setTimeout - не стоит первым аргументом передавать строку - это некрасиво и плохо. Передавайте функции.
- Array.forEach(...).length - не работает, forEach не возвращает this.

2) Что-то в этом духе:

```
var once = false;
function func() {
    if (once) return;
    once = true;
    //...
}
```

3) Отвяжите евент onContextMenu от второго элемента и разбейте функцию my_contextmenu на две

p.s. похоже на тестовое задание, перед тем как делать такие вещи начните с простого